# How to return the difference value from array of objects?

Tags: javascript

Here is the item1 data:

```js
const item1 = [
  {
   
    "proposedWaterClosets": 2,
    "proposedToilets": 3,
    "noOfWaterClosets": 3,
    "noOfToilets": 3
  },
  {
    
    "proposedWaterClosets": 2,
    "proposedToilets": 3,
    "noOfWaterClosets": 4,
    "noOfToilets": 2
  }
]
```

Here is the item2 data: **OPTIONAL
**

```
const item2 = {
    
    "proposedWaterClosets": 2,
    "proposedToilets": 3,
    "noOfWaterClosets": 3,
    "noOfToilets": 3
  }
```

I want the output to be like this which only return the difference value

expected output:

```
[{
    "noOfToilets": 2,
    "noOfWaterClosets":4
}]
```

Here I am having issue , I am getting which the value is same .. here is my approach using map and with the help of if condition, the thing is  I am getting the output which is equal ... Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
 const result = item1.map((it) => {
    if (it.noOfToilets !== item2.noOfToilets || it.noOfWaterClosets !== item2.noOfWaterClosets) {
      return { oldToilets: it.noOfToilets, oldWaterC: it.noOfWaterClosets };
    }
  });
```

getting output: `[{oldToilets::2,oldWaterC:3}]`

UPDATE: ** Compare the array of objects can work also

Comment: The code you have shared has nothing to do with question. Please share any relevant code

Comment: why do you want to get the result above? how do you calculate the result?

Comment: I am iterating the array and comparing with the item2 to check the difference  @NinaScholz

Comment: i see different values. is the result the real result from given data?

Comment: The first index of item1 is same with the item2.. the only difference is the index 2 @NinaScholz so I want to get the value from the index 2... use case may be different for index

Answer (score 0):

If the object will remain a simple k-v mapping and not include nested objects, you can make a simple check like this:

```js
function difference(a, b) {
  const diff = {};
  const allKeys = [];

  // collect all the keys and make sure there are no duplicates
  for (const key of [...Object.keys(a), ...Object.keys(b)]) {
    if (!allKeys.includes(key)) {
      allKeys.push(key);
    }
  }

  for (const key of allKeys) {
    // if this key-value is the same, ignore
    if (a[key] === b[key]) {
      continue;
    }

    // save only the difference
    diff[key] = b[key];
  }
  
  return diff;
}

const item1 = {
  "proposedWaterClosets": 2,
  "proposedToilets": 3,
  "noOfWaterClosets": 3,
  "noOfToilets": 3
}

const item2 = {
  "proposedWaterClosets": 2,
  "proposedToilets": 3,
  "noOfWaterClosets": 3,
  "noOfToilets": 2
}

console.log(difference(item1, item2))
```

Note that in your example, item1 is an array of objects, and item2 is one object... They aren't normally comparable (they will always return difference).

If you iterate over the objects in the array and can compare between them, this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Let's say I have 5-10 array of objects, in this scenario your code might not feasible. for now it is only 2 objects

Comment: Iterate through both the arrays together, and use the function to compare each object in the 1st array to the relevant object in the 2nd array. If you want the difference only on the same index in both arrays, 1 loop should do it. If you need each object in the 1st array to check against all the objects in the 2nd, use a nested loop

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries from the object and mapp the objects with difference.

```js
const
    array = [{ proposedWaterClosets: 2, proposedToilets: 3, noOfWaterClosets: 3, noOfToilets: 3 }, { proposedWaterClosets: 2, proposedToilets: 3, noOfWaterClosets: 4, noOfToilets: 2 }],
    object = { proposedWaterClosets: 2, proposedToilets: 3, noOfWaterClosets: 3, noOfToilets: 3 },
    entries = Object.entries(object),
    result = array.flatMap(o => {
        const pairs = Object
            .entries(o)
            .filter(([k, v]) => object[k] !== v);
        return pairs.length
            ? Object.fromEntries(pairs)
            : []
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: OUTPUT should be     "noOfToilets": 2

Comment: sorry. please see edit.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, your code is quite okay.. but output [
    {
        "proposedWaterClosets": 4
    },
    {
        "noOfToilets": 2
    }
]

isn't this quite expensive to again push the object to another empty array  ..to get the desired output to be like this [
    {
        "proposedWaterClosets": 4,
        "noOfToilets": 2

    }
 
]
@Nina

Comment: please add the data for this result to the question. what does not work?

Comment: already mention in the question desired output: [{proposedWaterClosets:2, noOfToilets:3}] @Nina

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it via creating a custom compare function.

**Demo :**

```js
const item1 = [
  {
    "proposedWaterClosets": 2,
    "proposedToilets": 3,
    "noOfWaterClosets": 3,
    "noOfToilets": 3
  },
  {

    "proposedWaterClosets": 2,
    "proposedToilets": 3,
    "noOfWaterClosets": 3,
    "noOfToilets": 2
  }
];

const item2 = {
  "proposedWaterClosets": 2,
  "proposedToilets": 3,
  "noOfWaterClosets": 3,
  "noOfToilets": 3
}

function compare(arr, obj) {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach((item1Obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(item2 => {
      if (obj[item2] !== item1Obj[item2]) {
        res[item2] = item1Obj[item2];
      }
    });
  });
  return res;
}

console.log(compare(item1, item2));
```

Comment: Is it feasible for  huge data for now comparing 2 objects is fine ..Let's say it has more than 2

Comment: yes it will work with any number of objects in an array.